# How to make a vegetarian coffee jelly?

Tags: coffee, jelly

I have tried to make coffee jelly with agar, but that was disappointing. Even high-quality beans did not get me any good result, compared with gelatin-based recipes: The texture is different, but it is mainly the taste that disturbed me. I expect, perhaps, to have a neutral base for the jelly, so that the coffee flavour remains plain and strong. I also like the smoothness of gelatin compared with, say, agar.

Is there a good combination of beans and ingredients to make a vegetarian coffee jelly?

Som extra details:

- Tried with agar only.
- Hot coffee added to the mix.
- Temperature-room cooling, then fridge cooling.

Comment: Could you please clarify: Did you use hot or cooled coffee, what were the good / fail recipes?

Comment: Have you used agar before? The texture is never the same as that of gelatine, so if that's your expenctation, the jelly will always "fail".

Comment: Thank you for your feedbacks. I have tried to refine the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I've used agar agar before with [this](http://www.youtoocancook.net/2015/01/coffee-jelly-using-agar-agar-agar-agar.html) recipe. Although I've never tried it myself with coffee beans, the trick might be to use instant coffee, which is what I find is almost the case with other desserts with coffee flavor. I also add 1 teaspoon of vanilla essence right at the end, which lifts the flavor and also sieve before letting it set. I generally put it in the fridge and speed up the setting process.

Answer (score 2):

With gelatin on the glossy, bouncy, and stretchy end, and agar sort of on the opposite... perhaps OP can try konnyaku, a starch developed by the Japanese and currently much used in their (& Chinese & Korean) snack products...

It's from a root plant, and behaves somewhere inbetween the gelatin and agar... Glossy and bouncy like the former (stretches just a tad less), vegan like the latter, and remains comfortably solid in room temperature...

In Hong Kong Starbucks I've had a cold latte with little coffee jelly cubes in it... Think it's konnyaku from the texture... While I think it's from a supplier, what OP wants to make definitely exists...

So do look it up and see how it works out, eh ?